# Use of Hashmap values using loop

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I have a screen with 5 fields. I have created one excel file with 5 columns and 10 rows. I want to store the values of excel in hashmap and use each row value in fields to perform a save action. I need to use the Excel class which is under Framework to read entries. Working code:

```
hmCreateAdvBank=Excel.getXlsRowDataAsMap(TestFile, TestSheet, "1");
Page.Field1.setText(hmCreateAdvBank.get("Key Value"));
Save();
```

TestFile & TestSheet are variables carrying the values of Excel file name and sheet name.

When I use a for loop and replace the integer value with a defined variable it gives me an error like:

```
Stack Trace: null    
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.libs.Excel.getXlsRowDataAsMap(Excel.java:786)
```

I am new to this world so brushing up with stackoverflow and your help.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you're just asking how to use a for loop.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Yes, I have a excel function which has 3 parameters. 1. File Name 2. Sheet Name 3. Row No - I want to use loop for each row present in excel file. Reading a File is covered in Excel Function. But, row no is the one which is causing issue to me.

Comment: What is "Key Value"? Is it the name of a column?

Comment: There is a first row having title (field names of screen) which we are using as Key Value. So excel function is helping in that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you will need to iterate through a Map. The most efficient way to iterate is as shown below :

```
    Map<String,String> theMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for(Entry<String,String> entry : theMap.entrySet()){
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
    }
```

Comment: I have a function which reads a single record. hmRecord= Excel.getXlsRowDataAsMap(testFile, testSheet, rowNo); Now, I want to use a loop for rowNo.

Comment: The getXlsRowDataAsMap method takes in as a parameter a String as a number, are you parsing the number as a String. For example : String iString = Integer.parseint(i)? and then passing in the String "iString"?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: So is this what you want?

```
// iterate over all rows
for(int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {

    // convert the row number to a String
    String rowStr = String.valueOf(row);

    // get the row data
    Map<String, String> rowData = Excel.getXlsRowDataAsMap(TestFile, TestSheet, rowStr);
    Page.Field1.setText(rowData.get("Column1"));
    Page.Field2.setText(rowData.get("Column2"));
    Page.Field3.setText(rowData.get("Column3"));
    Page.Field4.setText(rowData.get("Column4"));
    Page.Field5.setText(rowData.get("Column5"));
    Save();
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Due to framework limitation, I could not use the approach adviced by you. Any other alternative?

Comment: @ Adriaan Koster: Yes, This is what I want. Thanks for helping out on this. This really helps.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can loop through a hashmap's values with a foreach loop

```
package hashmap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashmapLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        myMap.put("someKey", "someValue");
        myMap.put("otherKey", "otherValue");

        for(String s : myMap.values()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a solution. Iterating over HashMap values does not preserve order and OP needs to correlate the column contents with specific fields in his application.